# In Jasmine, what's the correct way to get the specs and results in an object?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/n85auoan/14/), I'm writing some test cases and trying to capture results of those test cases in an object, so that I can print the results on the page the way I want. I'm basically trying to recreate coding challenges in freecodecamp.

When done correctly, I should be able to pass in any test suite I want so that developers can later write code to pass those test suites.

Right now, to get the jasmine spec descriptions and results, I do this

```
var env = jasmine.getEnv();
env.execute();
var specResults = env.currentSpec.suite.specs_;
```

When I console-log `specResults`, I have properties `failedCount` and `passedCount` deep inside it, that lets me identify whether a spec has passed or failed. However when I reuse the same object by copying it inside another object, they have incorrect values.

In this particular example, `specsArray[2].passed` is supposed to be `false` because `specResults[2].results.failedCount` is not equal to `0`. But it's `true`. Why?